# custom urlheader for blog in asp .net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

net mvc 3 and trying to create a blog application. I want to have a url which contains a urlheader such as:

Blog/Details/Third-post

However, I am getting a url which is this:

```
Blog/Details/3?urlHeader=Third-post
```

what am I doing wrong?

My blog controller is as follows:

```
public ViewResult Details(int id, string urlHeader)
{
    var blogs = blogrepository.GetBlog(id);
    var recentblogs = blogrepository.FindRecentBlogs(5);
    var archivelist = blogrepository.ArchiveList();
    BlogDetailsViewModels viewModel = new BlogDetailsViewModels { Blog = blogs, RecentBlogs = recentblogs, ArchiveList = archivelist };
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

and the route method is as follows:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
        "BlogDetail", // Route name
        "Blog/Details/{urlHeader}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Blog", action = "Details" }, // Parameter defaults
        new { urlHeader = "" } // Parameter constraints
    );
```

and the link is as follows:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Model.Title , "Details", "Blog", new { id = Model.BlogID, urlHeader = Model.UrlHeader }, null)
```

Comment: There's something incoherent here. You are passing an `id` parameter in your ActionLink but there's no `{id}` placeholder in your route definition (actually there is - in the default route which I suspect you have kept as well and which is conflicting with this new route). If you expect `Blog/Details/Third-post` as url, what's the point of giving `id = Model.BlogID`? Don't you want the target url to be `Blog/Details/3/Third-post`?

Comment: id is required by the http post details blog controller to fetch the correct blog post

Comment: Alright, then fix your question in which you wrote that you want `Blog/Details/Third-post` as url which is not true. You want `Blog/Details/3/Third-post`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have the following routes:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Blog",
        "Blog/Details/{id}/{urlHeader}",
        new { controller = "Blog", action = "Details", urlHeader = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new { id = @"\d+" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```